# return type for method with runnable in it

Tags: android, android-room, threadpoolexecutor

I'm using an executor for background operations. I have a method that takes data from a Room Database and returns a string, so that I can send it from the repository into a viewmodel into activity.

How can I return a string in the method while there is a runnable in it? Please see the following code for a better description:

```
 public String singleLoad(final int id){
    DefaultExecutorSupplier.getInstance().forBackgroundTasks()
            .execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    favNewsDao.loadSingle(id);
                }
            });
    return favNewsDao.loadSingle(id);

}
```

The return gives an exception, saying that it cannot access the database on the Main Thread. How can I get a string from this method, like I have in this ViewModel class

```
public String singleLoad(int id) {
    return repository.singleLoad(id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an Executor you can use an ExecutorService and submit a Callable. More information here: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit(java.util.concurrent.Callable%3CT%3E)

Answer (score 0):

> **First Approach**

In Repository class, use [`CountDownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) with a count value of 1, and with until it reaches 0 to return back the correct result this can be achieved by using `await()` of this `CountDownLatch` which allows to urge executing the underlying code until the latch count value reaches 0.

```
CountDownLatch mLatch;
String singleLoad;

public String singleLoad(final int id){

    mLatch = new CountDownLatch(1); // latch count is 1

    DefaultExecutorSupplier.getInstance().forBackgroundTasks()
            .execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    singleLoad = favNewsDao.loadSingle(id);
                    mLatch.countDown(); // Now you can allow returning back the result (id)
                }
            });

    // Don't return now and wait until the Executer is done
    try {
        // Application's main thread awaits, till the 
        // CountDownLatch count value reaches 0
        mLatch.await(); 

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return mId;

}
```

> **UPDATE**

As first approach might have memory leak, here is a second approach by using a listener instead of `CountDownLatch`.

> **Second Approach**

Here I am triggering a listener whenever the needed String is returned back from Room database to the Repository class; the listener is registered in the activity, cascaded to ViewModel, and then to the Repository.
The listener has a callback that retrieves the returned String from database which is eventually returned back to the activity.

**Dao interface**

```
@Dao
public interface MyDao {
    ...
    @Query("SELECT text FROM notes WHERE id = :id") // change types according to your database
    String loadSingle(int id);
}
```

**Repository**

```
public class AppRepository {

    // ...  non-relevent code is omitted

    private static Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    public interface OnTextListener {
        void onTextReceived(String text);
    }

    public void getNoteText(int id, OnTextListener listener) {
        executor.execute(() -> {
            String text = mDb.noteDao().loadSingle(id); // mDb is the database instance in repository 
            // trigger the listener in the ViewModel
            listener.onTextReceived(text);
        });
    }

}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class MainViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    // ...  non-relevent code is omitted

    public void getNoteText(int id, AppRepository.OnTextListener listener) {
        mRepository.getNoteText(id, listener);
    }
}
```

**Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // ...  non-relevent code is omitted

        // Retrieve single data from Room database
        int id = 39;
        mViewModel.getNoteText(id, new AppRepository.OnTextListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTextReceived(String text) {
                // The retrieved text from Room database
                Log.d(TAG, "onTextReceived: " + text);
                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
                }.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: isn't this cause memory leak ?

Comment: @TestITBabe please check updated answer with one more approach